# How to ignore first x characters when doing a Windows file search?

Tags: regex, windows, search, wildcard

Environment: Windows 2003 Server

Problem:
How can I ignore first x characters of the file name, when doing a Windows file search?
I am trying to find all files whose names contain a specific word, but the catch is, that I don't want to list the files which contain the search phrase in the first 10 letters of each file name.

How do I do this? Any tool that would allow me to do this?
I've found following tool GREPWIN: https://code.google.com/p/grepwin, which allows using REGEX for file searching, but I am not sure how to ignore first 10 letters using REGEX.

**EXAMPLE:**

Search word: **test**

Files:

- **testtestteBLAH.TXT** - this one will be ignored
- **BLAHBLAHBLtest.TXT** - this one should show in search

Search result:

**BLAHBLAHBLtest.TXT**

Comment: Time to [learn regular expressions!](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /s/b/a-d "%sourcedir%\*test*.*" ') DO (
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 SET "n10=%%~na"
 SET "n10=!n10:~0,10!"
 SET "n10a=!n10:test=!"
 IF /i "!n10a!" equ "!n10!" ECHO %%~a
 endlocal
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a simple batch job to perform that task. It doesn't use a regex. soz.

The `dir/s/b` produces a list of matching filenames. These are processed one-by-one by the `for` command as follows:

select the first 10 characters of the **name** part, then replace any string `test` in those 10 characters with *nothing*. If the result is *no change* then show the filename.

Naturally, you could replace `test` throughout with `%1` and run as

*thisbatch* test

- replace `test` with `zork` or `puffin` or whatever.

You could also replace `10` with a parameter for a different length-selection or have the directoryname as a parameter too, if you like.

---

To search within the files located, you could replace

```
ECHO %%~a
```

with

```
(
 findstr "thingtosearchfor" "%%~a"
)
```

Which would show you the lines in the files that contain the target string (but see the `findstr` documentation for details of how the `find` part works - you don't indicate what you want to find)

or with

```
(
 findstr "thingtosearchfor" "%%~a" >nul
 if not errorlevel 1 ECHO %%~a
)
```

if you want to show the filename in which the text to be found is found.

Note that the parentheses are important in the second case since it's a multi-line command, optional in the first

Comment: That's a very nice solution indeed, because it doesn't require any third party tool... I am marking this as accepted answer.

Comment: Magoo, could you also post a script for searching within content of the files? So, not just file names?

Answer (score 1):

Simply consume (or require) that there be at least ten characters which have to preceded the wording of test:

```
.{10}test
```

This regex works because no match will happen without 10 characters then a `test`.

Comment: I've tested it, but it didn't work. Following worked though: (?<=.{10})test , check: https://regex101.com/r/nD1uP1/1

Comment: @jjj Which parser did you use? I used `.Net`'s parser.

Comment: I don't even see option there for .Net, it works in PHP and Python and I am successfully using the regex above in my search using PowerGREP tool.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research online, I've worked out following REGEX to ignore first 10 letter: 
(?<=.{10})test
You can see it working in my demo at: regex101.com/r/nD1uP1/1
I've used PowerGREP (http://www.powergrep.com/) tool on Windows with above regex search query and it worked.